# Combine two batch script operating on names and text

Tags: batch-file

I need batch script for prepare developer files for production environment.

First Main script (Changing database names inside of text file):

```
@echo on 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "search=GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE."
set "replace=WEB_APP_SOURCE."

set "textFile=GSC*.txt"
set "rootDir=."

for /R "%rootDir%" %%j in ("%textFile%") do (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%%~j" echo(!line!)
    endlocal
)

)

endlocal
```

Second script (Changing database names in name of text file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE.*) do (
set "name=%%F"
ren "!name!" "!name:GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE.=WEB_APP_SOURCE.!"
)
```

Currently i don't know how to prepare one script which will be working on all text files even in sub-folders. First case of script will change all found values inside of text second case change name of file. The last one (i don't find solution yet) will be change EOL Conversion into Unix (LF). Currently after use first script that changing into Windows CR LF.

Comment: Surely, instead of changing the content directly to the same file, you'd change it to a new file with the new name at the same time, then just delete the old file afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how i completed that task.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "search=GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE."
set "replace=WEB_APP_SOURCE."
set "textFile=GSC*.txt"
set "rootDir=."
for /R "%rootDir%" %%j in ("%textFile%") do (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%%~j" echo(!line!)
    endlocal
)
)
endlocal
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%F in (*GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE*) do (
set filename="%%~nxF"
ren "%%F" "!filename:GSC_WEB_APP_SOURCE=WEB_APP_SOURCE!"
)
endlocal
```